# Why not visit a grave twice in a day?

Tags: cemetery-grave

I came across this in *Mishna B'rura* 581:27:

> ואין לילך על קבר אחד ב״פ ביום אחד.‏

That is, roughly:

> And one should not go to one grave twice in one day.

(This is in *Baer Hetev* :17 also, who cites the *Arizal* as a source.) Why not?

---

(I translate it as "go to" not "walk on" in light of *MB* 539:41, who in that way interprets the same phrase in *Rama* there, and who says not to walk on a grave altogether.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Daily Halacha](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=262) brings this in the name of Rabbi Yehuda HaChasid and says that this restriction is Kabalistic.

[Nitei Gavriel - Aveilus2 88:1:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=668) mentions this in the name of Magein Avraham 581:16 quoting the Arizal, Rabbi Yehuda HaChasid 12, Shela, Elya Raba 224:7, Rabbi Akiva Eiger 376 and others. In note 2 he brings a possible reason from Damesek Eliezer. That by returning the same day you are showing that the departed did not intercede on your behalf and it is a shame for the departed to do so.